# Обработка input radio

Tags: input, ajax, php

Есть поле input, которое в зависимости от выбранных настроек выполняет либо функцию добавления в базу данных, либо поиск по базе данных с указанной маской.
Сама форма:

```
<form method="post">
        <p>Фамилия участника :
        <p><input id="new_partner" name="name_partner" type="text" placeholder="Фамилия">
        <p> Режим работы:
            <p><input id="check" name="option1" type="radio"> Добавление нового участника
               <input id="check" name="option2" type="radio"> Поиск участника по указанной маске

         <div id="link" hidden>
            <p>Дополнительные настройки:
            <p><input id="check" name="option3" type="checkbox"> Автосортировка таблицы участников
         </div>

        <p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Выполнить" >
           <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Посмотреть весь список участников" >
    </form>
```

Как с помощью ajax проверять выбранные настройки radio input, чтобы при выборе пункта "Поиск участника по указанной маске" запускался скрипт ниже?

Скрипт, который совершает поиск с указанным условием (прописан для другого input):

```
$(function() {
    $("#search").keyup(function(){
        var search = $("#search").val();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/action",
            data: {"search": search},
            cache: false,                       
            success: function(response){
                $("#resSearch").html(response);
            }
        });
        return false;

    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Добавьте в html значения `value` у radiobutton'ов, а `name` должен быть одинаковый у них:

```
<input id="check" name="optionRadio" value="1" type="radio"> Добавление нового участника
<input id="check" name="optionRadio" value="2" type="radio"> Поиск участника по указанной маске
```

Теперь вам нужно получить `value` у выбранного button'а в режиме их переключения:

```
$('input[name=optionRadio]').change(function() {
      var value = $('input[name=optionRadio]:checked').val();
});
```

А дальше, исходя из полученного значения, стройте свою логику поведения кнопки. [Пример](http://jsfiddle.net/prof5rLo/1/)